# List of UK hill climbs

Tags: racing, uk

Can anyone provide a brief list of some graded climbs in England, Scotland and Wales, please? I tackled a few hills some 30 years ago (as a tourist), which I thought were quite tough - would they be a challenge to a racing cyclist (at racing speeds)? Examples include Berriedale Brae, Carter Bar, Drumochter. I used granny gears and went very slooooowly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Strava website to find categorised segments. You'll have to register for an account and I'm not sure how "official" the categories are.

1. Go to [Strava.com](http://www.strava.com/)
2. Register or sign in Click on "Explore" menu
3. Find the region you're interested in using the search box.
4. The map will then show all segments registered in Strava.
5. There is a slider along the top that allows you to filter out various categories, so you can see just categorised climbs.

Comment: [Here is an explanation](https://strava.zendesk.com/entries/20420292-how-are-strava-climbs-categorized-for-rides) of how the climbs are categorised (essentially using the UCI calculation, but ignoring the subjective difficulty). [This is](http://i.imgur.com/Ny2Pk.png) what the segment explorer looks like - my only complaint is quite a few of the stepper segments are unsuitable to road-bikes, but this is hard to determine short of using street-view to check

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guardian article about the top 10 climbs in UK :

http://www.guardian.co.uk/travel/2012/jul/13/top-10-uk-cycle-climbs