# Great/Classic climbs near Lausanne

Tags: bikeroutes, climbing

Are there any "classic", highly regarded, or even little known gem climbs around Lausanne - within range of Lausanne, maybe maximum 60-80 km out so it could be ridden in a day with Lausanne as a base, ideally closer to Lausanne the better!

*I'm not sure if this is off-topic, for me this is a cycling question and the help pages gave no guidance on this sort of question and similar questions appear to have been asked previously... [List of UK hill climbs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10281/list-of-uk-hill-climbs).*

Comment: (I'm on a three day course there next month and considering adding one or two days to take my bike)

Comment: I've been around that area a bit, but not as a cyclist. There are none of your classic TdF climbs around there, they're all quite some way further south, but it is a good area for riding in general, and of course it is naturally hilly.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have not ridden in Lausanne, I rely upon [Stava](http://www.strava.com/). I don't know if you can follow the links posted below without being a member, if not then you can join up for free.

Once on Stava, going to the Activity Search page, I enter *Lausanne, Switzerland* and hit search.

A few interesting rides come up ... there are many others too ...

- [Along the lake side to Chexbres and up Mont Pèlerin](http://www.strava.com/activities/178367095) 55 km, 2:45-3 hrs, 860 m climbing, 8 x cat 4 climbs, 1 cat 3.
- [Mt Tendre](http://www.strava.com/activities/78831021) 82 km, 3:25-whatever hrs, 1527 m climbing, 5 x cat 4 climbs, 1 x cat 2, 2 x cat HC climbs.
- [Col de la Croix](http://www.strava.com/activities/71334522/segments/1394044168) 145 km, 6 hrs - whatever, 3,283 m climbing, 10 x cat 4 climbs, 3 x cat 3 climbs, 3 x cat 2 climbs, 1 x cat 1 climb.

Comment: That's great, hadn't tried the activity search - segment search had also thrown out a few candidates. Those routes look really tempting!

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: Maybe you could post your rides later?